# Counting Sizes of Parabolic Subgroups of $Sp_n$ over $\mathbb F _q$

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, block-matrices

I would like to count the size of a stabilizer of an arbitrary flag $\mathcal F$ in $Sp_n$ over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$. I am so far basing my attempt to count off of Paul Garrett's [book on buildings](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/buildings/book.pdf), which has provided me with the guidance that counting the size of this is equivalent to counting the size of the Levi component and the unipotent radical, since $$P=M\rtimes R_uP$$ where $P$ is the parabolic subgroup stabilizing $\mathcal F$, $M$ is the Levi component, and $R_uP$ is the unipotent radical.

To begin with, I am trying to just count the size of $P$ for a flag with just one vector space, which, as outlined in his book, consists of matrices with entries like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgCzZ.png). But then it says that there are further conditions which must be satisfied for the matrix to lie in $Sp_n$, which I am assuming are the relations described for any element of this group, which he gives earlier in the chapter, for a matrix $(a,b \backslash c, d)$ $$c^t a-a^t c = 0 \quad d^t b-b^t d = 0 \quad d^ta-b^tc=1$$ How do I count the number of matrices with entries that satisfy this criteria? If someone knows of a better way to do this with the Levi and unipotent radical components, then that would be appreciated as well. The standard Levi component seems to be easier to count, as $$|M|=|GL_l||SP_{n-l}|$$ but the unipotent radical gives me the same difficulty to count. Any help would be appreciated.